# How to prevent EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO with JNA?

Tags: java, dll, crash, jna

I receive the follow sporadic crash with JNA. Are there any JNA settings to prevent this?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO (0xc000008e) at pc=0x0000000000b6ec60, pid=2364, tid=3908
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_74-b02) (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.74-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~RuntimeStub::unwind_exception Runtime1 stub
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# ....\hs_err_pid2364.log
Compiled method (c1)  425393 12999   !   3       database.DatabaseUtils::executeQuery (83 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00000000028d1350,0x00000000028d2e98] = 6984
 relocation     [0x00000000028d1470,0x00000000028d15b0] = 320
 main code      [0x00000000028d15c0,0x00000000028d26a0] = 4320
 stub code      [0x00000000028d26a0,0x00000000028d27a8] = 264
 oops           [0x00000000028d27a8,0x00000000028d27b8] = 16
 metadata       [0x00000000028d27b8,0x00000000028d2818] = 96
 scopes data    [0x00000000028d2818,0x00000000028d2bf0] = 984
 scopes pcs     [0x00000000028d2bf0,0x00000000028d2e20] = 560
 dependencies   [0x00000000028d2e20,0x00000000028d2e28] = 8
 handler table  [0x00000000028d2e28,0x00000000028d2e58] = 48
 nul chk table  [0x00000000028d2e58,0x00000000028d2e98] = 64
Compiled method (c1)  425394 12999   !   3       database.DatabaseUtils::executeQuery (83 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00000000028d1350,0x00000000028d2e98] = 6984
 relocation     [0x00000000028d1470,0x00000000028d15b0] = 320
 main code      [0x00000000028d15c0,0x00000000028d26a0] = 4320
 stub code      [0x00000000028d26a0,0x00000000028d27a8] = 264
 oops           [0x00000000028d27a8,0x00000000028d27b8] = 16
 metadata       [0x00000000028d27b8,0x00000000028d2818] = 96
 scopes data    [0x00000000028d2818,0x00000000028d2bf0] = 984
 scopes pcs     [0x00000000028d2bf0,0x00000000028d2e20] = 560
 dependencies   [0x00000000028d2e20,0x00000000028d2e28] = 8
 handler table  [0x00000000028d2e28,0x00000000028d2e58] = 48
 nul chk table  [0x00000000028d2e58,0x00000000028d2e98] = 64
Compiled method (c1)  425394 12999   !   3       database.DatabaseUtils::executeQuery (83 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00000000028d1350,0x00000000028d2e98] = 6984
 relocation     [0x00000000028d1470,0x00000000028d15b0] = 320
 main code      [0x00000000028d15c0,0x00000000028d26a0] = 4320
 stub code      [0x00000000028d26a0,0x00000000028d27a8] = 264
 oops           [0x00000000028d27a8,0x00000000028d27b8] = 16
 metadata       [0x00000000028d27b8,0x00000000028d2818] = 96
 scopes data    [0x00000000028d2818,0x00000000028d2bf0] = 984
 scopes pcs     [0x00000000028d2bf0,0x00000000028d2e20] = 560
 dependencies   [0x00000000028d2e20,0x00000000028d2e28] = 8
 handler table  [0x00000000028d2e28,0x00000000028d2e58] = 48
 nul chk table  [0x00000000028d2e58,0x00000000028d2e98] = 64
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: As far as I understand this should not happen, unless you changed the FPU control register contents (or some code you called did). See this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dougste/2008/11/12/random-and-unexpected-exception_flt_divide_by_zero-and-exception_flt_invalid__operation/

Comment: Yes, of course the register is changed. It is code from Microsoft which do it.